# Перехват нажатия клавиши в другом приложении VisualStudio

Tags: c#, winapi

Всем привет,использую данный хук

```
class globalKeyboardHook
        {

            public struct keyboardHookStruct
            {
                public int vkCode;
                public int scanCode;
                public int flags;
                public int time;
                public int dwExtraInfo;
            }

            const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
            const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
            public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
            IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
            public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
            public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

            public globalKeyboardHook()
            {
                hook();
            }

            ~globalKeyboardHook()
            {
                unhook();
            }

            public void hook()
            {

                IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
                //hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
                delegateHookProc = hookProc;
                hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, delegateHookProc, hInstance, 0);
            }
            public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);
            keyboardHookProc delegateHookProc;

            public void unhook()
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
            }
            public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
            {
                if (code >= 0)
                {
                    Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                    if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                    {
                        KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                        if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                        {
                            KeyDown(this, kea);
                        }
                        else
                            if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                            {
                                KeyUp(this, kea);
                            }
                        if (kea.Handled)
                            return 1;
                    }
                }
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
            }

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        }
```

Но не срабатывает отлов клавиши в другом приложении.Вызываю так:

```
private void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsSuspend)
            {
                    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("proccess"))
                    {
                        IsSuspend = true;
                        Suspend(process.Id);
                        timer1.Start();
                    }
            }
        }
```

Цель в том,чтобы в любом окне,не зависимо от того свернута программа или нет(по умолчанию висит в трее) при нажатии на клавишу F10(внесена в

```
globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook(); 
gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F10);
            gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
```

)

Программа выполняла необходимое мне действие один раз и оставалась висеть в фоне,пока клавиша снова не будет нажата.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный хук не будет работать во всех приложениях при запуске в обычном режиме. Вам придется запускать программу от имени администратора. Для того чтобы программа всегда запускалась от имени администратора нужно в ваше ПО добавить манифест и взамен этой строки :

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

поставить :

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```